# Wait for promise before rendering with @loadable/component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using the library [@loadable/component](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components) with react routes, for code splitting etc.

```
const AsyncViewItem = loadable(() => import("./modules/Items/View/View"));

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/items/:item" render={(props) => <AsyncViewItem {...props} fallback={LoadingPage} />} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Inside my `AsyncViewItem` class, I need to make a few promises to display the data I need.

```
export default class View extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.param = this.props.match.params.item;

        this.state = {
            chartOffers: [],
            item: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        equipmentService.getOne(this.param)
            .then((item) => {
                offerService.getChartMonth(this.param)
                    .then((data) => {
                        this.setState({ chartOffers: data, item: item[0] });
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        return console.error(error);
                    }); 
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return console.error(error);
            })
    }

    render() {
        const item = this.state.item;
        return (<div>{item.name}</div>);
    }
}
```

What I want to know is how I can make the `LoadingPage` fallback to display while those promises haven't returned anything yet (or haven't set the value of states)? Because, while it is loading, I will see an empty div and that's not very pleasable for user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `if` inside `render()` function, for example:

```
 render() {
        const item = this.state.item;
        if(item.length === 0) {
          return <div>loading...</div>;
        }
        return (<div>{item.name}</div>);
    }
```

Comment: I figured as much. Is there no way to do it natively with the library? Been looking around a bit but no luck.